# RSpec: How could I use the array include matcher in the expect syntax

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, rspec

I use [new RSpec syntax](http://myronmars.to/n/dev-blog/2012/06/rspecs-new-expectation-syntax) (`expect` instead of `should`) and I'd like to test if an array includes elements of another array. In the old syntax it would be:

```
array1.should include(array2)
```

In the new syntax I tried to write:

```
expect(array1).to include(array2)
```

but I got an error (that's quite reasonable):

```
TypeError: wrong argument type Array (expected Module)
```

Then I wrote:

```
expect(array1).to be_include(array2)
```

but it's ugly and it didn't work: apparently it checks if array2 is element of array1 not if all elements of array2 are included in array1.

Finally I wrote:

```
expect(array1 & array2).to eq(array2)
```

but it's not the prettiest solution. Do you know any better?

Answer (score 115, accepted):

You need to splat the arguments when passing them to the array matcher:

```
expect(array1).to include(*array2)
```

This is because you usually list out literals, e.g.:

```
expect([1, 2, 3]).to include(1, 2)
```

That said, `expect(array1).to include(array2)` should not fail with a weird error like you got, and in fact it works and passes in an example like:

```
  it 'includes a sub array' do
    array2 = ["a"]
    array1 = [array2]
    expect(array1).to include(array2)
  end
```

Comment: how I can test no inclusion? I tried `not_to include` but it raised an error:
`expect([1, 2, 3]).not_to include(1)` raises `RSpec::Expectations::ExpectationNotMetError: expected [1, 2, 3] not to include 1`

Comment: @IvánCortésRomero Your example is failing because `1` is in fact included in `[1,2,3]`, but you're telling rspec to expect it not to be. This passes: `expect([1, 2, 3]).not_to include(4)`.

Answer (score 15):

Try this one:

```
expect(array1).to include *array2
```

Answer (score 6):

To test if one array is subset of another array its perhapse good idea to introduce [set](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/set/rdoc/Set.html). And then you can write it like this... (Solution uses [Set#subset?](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/set/rdoc/Set.html#method-i-subset-3F))

```
require "set"

describe "Small test" do
  let(:array1) { %w{a b c d} }
  let(:array2) { %w{b c} }

  let(:array1_as_set) { array1.to_set }
  let(:array2_as_set) { array2.to_set }

  subject { array2_as_set }

  context "inclusion of w/ \"expect\"" do
    it { expect(subject).to be_subset(array1_as_set) }
  end

  context "inclusion of w/ \"should\"" do
    it { should be_subset(array1_as_set) }
  end

end
```